# stack cannot build network - where's config.log?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a project to build with `stack` and it depends on `network`. When I do `stack build`, it says

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack23678/network-2.6.2.1/Setup.hs, /tmp/stack23678/network-2.6.2.1/.stack-work/dist/i386-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/stack23678/network-2.6.2.1/.stack-work/dist/i386-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/setup/setup ...
Configuring network-2.6.2.1...
...
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/stack23678/network-2.6.2.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Sure, I'd love to. But where is this `config.log`? Or how can I re-create it?

Just `cabal install network` (without `stack`) works fine but how could `stack build` use this?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get better information here, you can make sure all generated files are saved by manually building network:

```
stack unpack network-2.6.2.1
cd network-2.6.2.1
stack init
stack build
```

Comment: Thanks. (Meanwhile, I re-installed gcc, and this also solved my problem.) I confirm that the method from your answer saves generated files.

Answer (score 0):

I think `C compiler cannot create executables` means you don't have a working C compiler installed.

`config.log` is generated by the `configure` command, and I don't think `stack` saves that. `stack` does save other logging output in

```
~/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/...
```

It's the same as what was emitted to your terminal, so it may not help.

Comment: I do have a working compiler. As I said, `cabal install network` runs fine.